# getting error No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2

Tags: spring, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

I am spring spring 3.2. Here is my config file

```
 <bean id="legacyDataSource" name="legacydb" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.legacy.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.legacy.url}" />  
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.legacy.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.legacy.password}" />
</bean>

 <bean id="ls360DataSource" name="Ls360db" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" lazy-init="true" >
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.ls360.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.ls360.url}" />  
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.ls360.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.ls360.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="legacyTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="legacyEmf"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ls360TransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="ls360Emf"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="legacyEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="legacyDataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="vendorAdaptor" />         
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.softech.ls360.integration.regulators.plcb.domain"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>              
        </props>        
    </property>
</bean>   

<bean id="ls360Emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ls360DataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="vendorAdaptor" />         
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.softech.ls360.integration.regulators.plcb.domain"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>              
        </props>        
    </property>
</bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="....db" />
```

Here is my class

```
@Service("dbManager") 
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DatabaseManager {

    @PersistenceContext
    @Qualifier("legacyEmf")
    private EntityManager legacyEm;

    @PersistenceContext
    @Qualifier("ls360Emf")
    private EntityManager ls360Em;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<Object> getResultList(String query, Class mappingClass) throws Exception {

        //Query emQuery = legacyEm.createNativeQuery(query, mappingClass);

        //return  emQuery.getResultList();
        return null;

    } //end of findTraineeFromLegacy()
}
```

Now when i rum the code i get the following error

```
Error creating bean with name 'dbManager': Injection of persistence 
dependencies failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: 
expected single matching bean but found 2: legacyEmf,ls360Emf
```

Why i am getting this error. How can i solve it?

Thanks

Comment: same issue here, but the proposed solution doesn't work for unit-testing. Did you try spring junit test ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had the same issue today. Solved it doing the following:

First I've added the parameter unitName to @PersistenceContext to both entity manager properties:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="appPU")
@Qualifier(value = "appEntityManagerFactory")
private EntityManager appEntityManager;

@PersistenceContext(unitName="managerPU")
@Qualifier(value = "managerEntityManagerFactory")
private EntityManager managerEntityManager;
```

And in my configuration file I've added a property persistenceUnitName to my bean definitions:

```
<bean id="appEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="appPU" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="br.com.app.domain" />
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="managerEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="managerPU" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="br.com.app.domain" />
    ...
</bean>
```

Comment: This is weird because I'm having the exactly same problem today but the @Qualifier does not work =(.
 I'm pretty sure all my configurations are all right, could you please post your entire applicationContext?
 Thank you.

Comment: The solution does not work for junit test (`AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`), any idea why ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked for me. Using `@PersistenceContex` with unitName is enough to solve the injection. It's not necessary to use the `@Qualifier` because you are injecting the EntityManager instead the EntityManagerFactory

Answer (score 4):

Also I'd like to add once more useful comment: you need to extend the  section in the 'web.xml' file of your web-app. Since now you have 2 Entity Managers, you need 2 OpenEntityManagerInViewFilters. Look the example:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter1</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
         <param-value>appEntityManagerFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter1</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


<filter>
  <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>managerEntityManagerFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

<filter-mapping>

<filter-name>OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter2</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Pay attention on fact the name 'appEntityManagerFactory' in < param-value >appEntityManagerFactory< / param-value > = 'appEntityManagerFactory' in < bean id="appEntityManagerFactory".

Answer (score 2):

I also faced such problems and solved it. Please do the following to solve this error:

Add the following line to all your entity classes of both schema.

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="<persistenceUnit>")
transient EntityManager entityManager;
```

`<persistenceUnit>` is the name of the persistence unit you defined in the `persistence.xml` file.