# Multiple db with JPA and Spring

Tags: spring, jpa

I have an application that has to connct to two DBs.
I wrote two @Configuration's with the two dataSources, entityManagerFactories and transactionManagers, each named differently.

The JUnit tests over the two groups of @Repositories taken separately are ok, so each configuration is ok.

The problems come when I put it all toghether and have one application with the two connections.
At boot, Spring gives me a NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException, saying there are two entityManagers named differently:

```
NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: [...] expected single matching bean but found 2: db2EntityManagerFactory,db1EntityManagerFactory
```

Even if I specify @Qualifier for EntityManager in @Repository classes that Spring is unable to create, in this way:

```
@PersistenceContext
@Qualifier("db2EntityManagerFactory")   
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

it doesn't work.

I'm using Spring Platform 1.1.1.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use different PersistentContext names instead of `@Qualifier`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. How (and where) do I specify the persistence unit name with annotations?

Comment: `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "HERE")`

Comment: In the name of the persistence unit I must use the EntityManagerFactory bean name (so, in my case db2EntityManagerFactory)?

Comment: How are you using you EntityManagerFactory ? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833147/getting-error-no-qualifying-bean-of-type-javax-persistence-entitymanagerfactory

Comment: You put me on the right path Alexandre, thanks. I built the entityManagerFactory with annotations (no XML) using the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean class, but I wasn't specifying the persistence unit name, so I set it there (via the proper setter) and now it works.