# No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, graphql-java

I have two entity manager configurations for two separate databases but when I try to auto-wire an entity manager in to configure my GraphQLExecutor bean I get an exception stating that there are two beans that match the criteria even though I've specified a unit name in the PersistenceContext.

**Exception**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'graphQLExecutor': Injection of resource
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' available:
>   expected single matching bean but found 2:
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:321)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE] at
>   com.ogl.JpaDemoApplication.main(JpaDemoApplication.java:15)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' available:
>   expected single matching bean but found 2:
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveNotUnique(DependencyDescriptor.java:173)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:518)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:496)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:627)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:318)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     ... 17 common
>   frames omitted

**Entity Manager 1**

```
package com.ogl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.ogl.system", entityManagerFactoryRef = "companyEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "companyTransactionManager")
public class SystemJpaConfig {

  private final Environment environment;

  @Autowired
  public SystemJpaConfig(Environment environment) {
    this.environment = environment;
  }

  @Bean("systemEntityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean systemEntityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.ogl.system");
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("system");
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(systemDataSource());

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
    adapter.setShowSql(true);
    adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);

    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
  }

  @Bean
  DataSource systemDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("p4.datasource.driver"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("p4.system.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("p4.system.user"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("p4.system.password"));

    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager systemTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory((systemEntityManagerFactory().getObject()));

    return transactionManager;
  }
}
```

**Entity Manager 2**

```
package com.ogl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.ogl.company", entityManagerFactoryRef = "companyEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "companyTransactionManager")
public class CompanyJpaConfig {

  private final Environment environment;

  @Autowired
  public CompanyJpaConfig(Environment environment) {
    this.environment = environment;
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean("companyEntityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean companyEntityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.ogl.company");
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("company");
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(companyDataSource());

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
    adapter.setShowSql(true);
    adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);

    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
  }

  @Bean
  DataSource companyDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("p4.datasource.driver"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("p4.company.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("p4.company.user"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("p4.company.password"));

    return dataSource;
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager companyTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory((companyEntityManagerFactory().getObject()));

    return transactionManager;
  }
}
```

**Injection**

```
package com.ogl;

import org.crygier.graphql.GraphQLExecutor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class GraphQLJpaConfig {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "company")
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Bean
  public GraphQLExecutor graphQLExecutor() {
    return new GraphQLExecutor(entityManager);
  }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ogl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpa-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>jpa-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for JPA</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.crygier</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833147/getting-error-no-qualifying-bean-of-type-javax-persistence-entitymanagerfactory

Comment: Make one of the EntityManagers primary

Comment: In my case I had forgotten to add the *spring-boot-starter-data-jpa* maven dependency. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution by marking the class I was injecting with the EntityManager with @Component and then auto-wiring that class into the class that uses the GraphQLExecutor:

**New class marked @Component**

```
package p4;

import org.crygier.graphql.GraphQLExecutor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Component
public class CompanyGraphQLComponent {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "company")
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  public GraphQLExecutor graphQLExecutor() {
    return new GraphQLExecutor(entityManager);
  }
}
```

**Class auto-wiring CompanyGraphQLComponent**

```
package p4.rest.controllers;

import core_services.persistence.CompanyContextHolder;
import core_services.records.system.Company;
import graphql.ExecutionResult;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import p4.CompanyGraphQLComponent;
import p4.records.GraphQLQuery;

@RestController
public class GraphQLController {
  @Autowired
  private CompanyGraphQLComponent companyGraphQLComponent;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/graphql", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ExecutionResult postJson(@RequestBody GraphQLQuery graphQLQuery) {
    return companyGraphQLComponent.graphQLExecutor().execute(graphQLQuery.getQuery(), graphQLQuery.getVariables());
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need `@ComponentScan` as well?

Comment: @RossiRobinsion no you don't, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 6):

You have defined two entitymanager. Now you have to tell spring which one should injected. For this you can use the  `@Qualifier` Annotation:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "company")
@Qualifier(<Name of the entitimanager you want to use>)
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Comment: Added `@Qualifier("companyEntityManagerFactory")` and still get the same exception

Comment: @MJPearsall You are sure taht it is exactly the same exception?

Comment: As a qualifier value, I used the persistence-unit name (for me it was `default`).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try giving the annotation @Primary over entityManagerFactory and transactionManager in one of the configuration files once?

Comment: Added to CompanyJpaConfig and still get the same exception

Answer (score 1):

I have two datasources, marking one as primary solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

SystemJpaConfig.java

```
@Bean
public EntityManager entityManagerSystem(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    return systemEntityManagerFactory().getObject().createEntityManager();
}
```

CompanyJpaConfig.java

```
@Bean
@Primary
public EntityManager entityManagerSystem(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    return companyEntityManagerFactory().getObject().createEntityManager();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).