# Inject 2 (3 in the near future) different entityManagerFactory (or entityManager) in spring application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have Spring + JPA (Hibernate) project, at which i connect to **MsSQL** database, now i need to open a new connection but this time it will be for **MySQL**.
i am using XML configuration

```
<bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${spring.datasource.driverClassName}" />
   ....
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:packagesToScan="com.wsg.admin.api.model"
    p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter">

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            ....
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Configure the MySQL connection -->
<bean id="enduserDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${enduser.db.driver}" />
    ....
</bean>

<bean id="enduserEntityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="enduserDataSource" p:packagesToScan="com.wsg.admin.api.model"
    p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter">

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            ....
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="enduserTransactionManager" />

<bean id="enduserTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="enduserEntityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

then i try to inject the entityManager using the fragment

```
@Autowired
EntityManager entityManager;
```

but i get exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'brandServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `@Autowired` to inject an `EntityManager` use `@PersistenceContext` instead and specify the name of the resource to use.

Comment: @M.Deinum, can you provide an example using the XML configuration in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Thanks to [@Volceri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2419292/volceri)
i used the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18073628/1973933, as follow

add     `<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="appPU" />` to each of  `entityManagerFactory`

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" ...  >

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            ...
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="dataSourcePU" />
</bean>

<bean id="endUserEntityManagerFactory" ...  >

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            ...
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="enduserDataSourcePU" />
</bean>
```

and to inject the em objects, i used

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="dataSourcePU")
EntityManager entityManager;

@PersistenceContext(unitName="enduserDataSourcePU")
EntityManager endUserEntityManager;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have two Entity Manager's(From EntityMangaerFactory) you need to tell spring which specifix EntityManager you want to be Autowired. Use `@Qualifier`

```
@Autowired  
@Qualifier("enduserEntityManagerFactory")  // use bean id of the Entity Manager Factory you want to inject
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory

EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

More about this [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa)

Comment: from my XML configuration, what is the Qualifier value i can use ? regarding that i don't inject  em directly, instead i inject entityManagerFactory.

Comment: I did exactly like you described, but now i got  'javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress' error

Comment: Do you have `@Transactional` annotation on the method where you are calling database (I mean save, or updated  or delete operation). And also please don't create multiple tickets  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430321/inject-2-data-sources-into-springhibernate-application-always-throw-no-transact

Comment: yes i have @Transactional on the method and also on the bean