# Inject 2 Data sources into spring+hibernate application always throw no transaction is in progress error

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have Spring + JPA (Hibernate) project, at which i connect to **MsSQL** database, now i need to open a new connection but this time it will be for **MySQL**. i am using XML configuration

```
<bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${spring.datasource.driverClassName}" />
   ....
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:packagesToScan="com.wsg.admin.api.model"
    p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter">

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            ....
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="dataSourcePU" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Configure the MySQL connection -->
<bean id="enduserDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${enduser.db.driver}" />
    ....
</bean>

<bean id="enduserEntityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="enduserDataSource" p:packagesToScan="com.wsg.admin.api.model"
    p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter">

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            ....
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="enduserDataSourcePU" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="enduserTransactionManager" />

<bean id="enduserTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="enduserEntityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

then i try to inject the entityManager using the fragment

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="dataSourcePU")
EntityManager entityManager;

@PersistenceContext(unitName="enduserDataSourcePU")
EntityManager endUserEntityManager;
```

it works only for the first Database, but when try to persist on the second it returns error

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

i tried to annotated the method (which contains persist() call) with `@Transactional("transactionManager")` one time, and `@Transactional(value = "enduserTransactionManager")` the other time, the second entityManager always throw the same exception

i tried to separate the persist() call into different methods, and annotated each of the two method  `@Transactional("transactionManager")` and `@Transactional(value = "enduserTransactionManager")` but still get the same error

```
@Transactional(value = "enduserTransactionManager")
private void createNewBrandMySQL(Brand newBrand) {
```

and

```
@Transactional("transactionManager")
public Integer createNewBrand(Brand newBrand) throws EntityDoesntExistException { 
//this method calls createNewBrandMySQL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, by injecting one `em` directly an the other using `entityManagerFactory`

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "dataSourcePU")
EntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("enduserEntityManagerFactory")
EntityManagerFactory endUserEntityManagerFactory;

EntityManager endUserEntityManager;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    endUserEntityManager = endUserEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}
```