# Spring Boot 2.1.7RELEASE-NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-bean, spring-orm

While migrating Spring to Spring Boot2.1.7 facing a NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException.Bean condigurations are the xml files.We added that xml file using @ImportResources annotation

```
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.7.RELEASE)

log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
62  SybaseUnit  INFO   [main] openjpa.Enhance - You have enabled runtime enhancement, but have not specified the set of persistent classes.  OpenJPA must look for metadata for every loaded class, which might increase class load times significantly.
23  SybaseUnit  WARN   [main] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'SybaseUnit', root URL [Service/target/classes/]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.
30  SybaseUnit  WARN   [main] openjpa.Runtime - Could not create the optional validation provider. Reason returned: "A default ValidatorFactory could not be created."
2  MssqlUnit  INFO   [main] openjpa.Enhance - You have enabled runtime enhancement, but have not specified the set of persistent classes.  OpenJPA must look for metadata for every loaded class, which might increase class load times significantly.
1  MssqlUnit  WARN   [main] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'MssqlUnit', root URL [Service/target/classes/]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.
2  MssqlUnit  WARN   [main] openjpa.Runtime - Could not create the optional validation provider. Reason returned: "A default ValidatorFactory could not be created."
[WARNING] 
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataAccessService': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: sybaseEntityManagerFactory,mssqlEntityManagerFactory
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:357)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
        at com.ge.hcit.xer.app.services.api.XERServiceMain.main(XERServiceMain.java:41)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: sybaseEntityManagerFactory,mssqlEntityManagerFactory
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:572)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:531)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:697)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:670)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:180)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354)
        ... 21 more
```

XML bean configuration

```
<bean id="mssqlDataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" 
        depends-on="localConfig">

    </bean>

    <bean id="mssqlTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="mssqlEntityManagerFactory" />

    </bean>


    <bean id="mssqlEntityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" primary ="true">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="mssqlDataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="openJpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MssqlUnit" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" >
            <list>
                <value>com.datasource.jpa.dto</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>

<bean id="sybaseDataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" 
        depends-on="localConfig">       
    </bean>

    <bean id="sybaseTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="sybaseEntityManagerFactory" />
         <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="SybaseUnit" />

    </bean>


    <bean id="sybaseEntityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="sybaseDataSource" />

    </bean>
```

Also exclude  HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class in Spring boot main class
Refer the following link
[stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833147/getting-error-no-qualifying-bean-of-type-javax-persistence-entitymanagerfactory)

DataAccessService

```
@Repository

public class DataAccessService
{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(DataAccessService.class);

    private static final String DEFAULT_HOSTNAME = "localhost";

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="MssqlUnit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;
```

how can i do the same in xml file configurations

How can i set bean as "mssqlEntityManagerFactory" without removing xml bean definition.Following are made

```
1.add Primary ="true"
2.add unitName="MssqlUnit"
3.add Qualifer
```

but Still getting the same error

Comment: May be `<bean primary="true|false"/>` could help or putting of this beans into different profiles.

Comment: And possibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833147/getting-error-no-qualifying-bean-of-type-javax-persistence-entitymanagerfactory

Comment: You also can use `Qualifier` for your beans.

Comment: added primary on sybaseEntityManagerFactory still getting the error @AlexeyUsharovski

Comment: Also try `<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="managerPU" />` for all factories.

Comment: tried <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="managerPU" /> but same error happening

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot is resolving dependency by type and it is finding two implementation for javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory

1. sybaseEntityManagerFactory
2. mssqlEntityManagerFactory

All you need to is set one of your bean to primary which you want to be used

```
<bean primary="true|false"/>
```

like below

```
<bean id="mssqlEntityManagerFactory" primary="true" 
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="mssqlDataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="openJpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MssqlUnit" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" >
            <list>
                <value>com.datasource.jpa.dto</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

or you can load one bean conditionally, this [URL](https://medium.com/@the.usual.traveller/conditionally-load-beans-in-spring-using-xml-configuration-bae0e8e12159) might help you.

Comment: is it same stack trace ?

Comment: seems change in bean definition has no effect, can you remove one bean declaration from xml for debugging